# how to use proper looping to generate random permutation code in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I need to generate random unique code with permutations, I'm trying to use a fast way by using

```
import random

FullChar = 'CFKLMNPRTVWXY01234678'
entriess = []

for i in range(5):
    unique_code = ''.join(random.sample(FullChar, count))
    entry = (unique_code, flg_id, get_id, bcd)
    entriess.append(entry)
print(entriess)
```

**output**

```
example
[('6M7Y13F', None, None, None), ('XNMV714', None, None, None), ('4FMRLK7', None, None, None), ('4LYT2C6', None, None, None), ('0R61KNL', None, None, None)]
```

the printed code is indeed random, but I want to try another method to generate a random unique code with *numpy*, for the install process I use

```
pip install numpy
```

here's the code

```
import numpy as np

FullChar = 'CFKLMNPRTVWXY01234678' 
entries = []
result =''
test = np.random.permutation(len(FullChar))
for j in test[:7]:
    result += FullChar[j]
entry = (result, flg_id, get_id, bcd)
entries.append(entry)
print(entries)
```

**output**

```
example
[('WM6LF7P', None, None, None)]
```

**expected output**

```
example
[('W3PT1N6', None, None, None), ('KVC7864', None, None, None), ('R236FNY', None, None, None), ('XVF3PL2', None, None, None), ('6V2RFKC', None, None, None)]
```

how to use proper looping to generate permutation random code like import random?
thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I can't understand why there is a question. Notice how, in the original code, there is a loop `for i in range(5):`, and then all the code needed for one permutation goes inside that, and that is how you end up with 5 permutations? Notice how, in the second code, there is just the code that makes one permutation? So, if you want to use that code to make 5 permutations... the obvious thing is to **make the same loop** and put the code inside it? What exactly is the difficulty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

FullChar = 'CFKLMNPRTVWXY01234678' 
entries = []

for i in range(5):
    result = ''
    test = np.random.permutation(len(FullChar))
    for j in test[:7]:
        result += FullChar[j]
    entry = (result, None, None, None)
    entries.append(entry)

print(entries)
```

```
[('PT46017', None, None, None), ('TRF7P3W', None, None, None), ('4NRXMTC', None, None, None), ('XY8L603', None, None, None), ('1RXN6WL', None, None, None)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pull the indices from `FullChar` and then join them together, like so

```py
result = ''.join(FullChar[i] for i in np.random.permutation(len(FullChar)))
```